# Which Eclipse API is used to execute the "Override/implement Methods"menu?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-generation

I would like to know which Eclipse APIs are called to get the list of methods from a given interface AND code generate the list on a class that implements the interface. Basically I would like to understand how works the menu "Source > Override/Implement Methods..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Plug-in Menu Spy](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy) to find the class that implements any menu action in Eclipse. Press `Alt+Shift+F2` and then invoke the menu item you're interested in. Plug-in Spy will show a pop-up of information about that menu action, including a link to the class that implements the action.

In this specific case, the class is `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OverrideMethodsAction`.

Comment: Just to be sure: You need to have the PDE and the Eclipse sources installed, not just the Java IDE. I'm not sure if the OP is aware of that.